# laravel route not work when i deploy on server page not found

Tags: laravel

every thing work fine on my local machine. All laravel route work fine.
But after deploy laravel app to root/var/html/farhan/project
then no larave route work 
No even single login or signup page display 
what i need to do to fix that type of issue

Comment: Is it throwing error? What is the message? tell us more

Comment: in your console what error is shown?

Comment: Did you change the base url in your env file?

Comment: it is not throw any error . it just show me blank page on postman and this page not working on we

Comment: yes i change the base url in .env file . but not working

Comment: did you set public as your root directory

Answer (score 0):

Check if your document root is mapped with your Laravel public directory, and your storage folder is having proper permissions try setting `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `env` files to see detailed error